# Logic app - When a new email arrives in a shared mailbox (v2) is not triggering logic app

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard, o365-flow

I have a logic app that gets triggered when a new email arrives in a shared mailbox. Seems like trigger is not working when new email is in Inbox.

I created a new connection to the shared mailbox and authorized by myself, but still trigger is not working.

Error is below:

```
{
  "status": 404,
  "message": "The specified object was not found in the store., Default folder Inbox not found.\r\nclientRequestId: 697f665b-0967-43a3-ac56-fd1932fd91e6\r\nserviceRequestId: 9ffb5c7e-d6a9-44cc-92e3-17f3cdb7271f",
  "error": {
    "message": "The specified object was not found in the store., Default folder Inbox not found.",
    "code": "ErrorItemNotFound",
    "originalMessage": "The specified object was not found in the store., Default folder Inbox not found."
  },
  "source": "somesource"
}
```

[image]

Could you please let me know what permission my id should have on the shared mailbox to authorize the connection. Also, any other suggestion on how to fix this error?

Comment: hi, as documentation says here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/office365/#when-a-new-email-arrives-in-a-shared-mailbox-(v2) "Your account should have permission to access the mailbox for this operation to succeed". to get permission or the credentials for the shared mail box you will need to talk to your Exchange admin or a Microsoft 365 global admin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reproducing from my end, I have observed that you receive this error when the trigger connection that you have given doesn't have enough permissions or isn't a valid Mailbox address.

[image]

Below are the few ways that can make this work

1. Make sure you provide a valid Mailbox Address. If trying to provide dynamically, either try manually providing Folder name or Mailbox Address.
2. Make sure you wait for 1 day after your account has been added to shared mailbox and given enough permissions.

After providing the mailbox address manually, I could able to view folders without any error.

[image]